# UFW Enable requires y prompt, how to automate with Bash Script?

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

I'm trying to automate the setup of UFW on an Ubuntu 16.04 instance. However when I type:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

I get prompted to enter yes or no, is there a way to feed it yes or set it automatically to start without getting stuck with a prompt?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about:

```
$ echo "y" | sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: Will try this right now!

Answer (score 53):

You could use:

```
$ sudo ufw --force enable
```

Comment: I had to check the manpage to be sure `--force` doesn't do anything unexpected: "By  default,  ufw will prompt when enabling the firewall while running under ssh. This can be disabled by using 'ufw --force enable'."

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

`yes` allows you to answer all questions from a program with `y`.

```
yes | sudo ufw enable
```